# To prove whether a iid sequence of Bernoulli RV is a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $Y_{n}$, $n≥0$ be an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli $(p)$ random variables for some fixed $p ∈
(0, 1).$

Let $X_{n} = Y_{n−1} + 2Y_{n}$ for $n ≥ 1$. Is $X_{n}$, $n≥1$ a Markov chain? If no explain why not. If
yes then determine initial distribution and transition matrix.

I am able to figure out that this is indeed a Markov chain How I did that:

$X_{n-1} = Y_{n−2} + 2Y_{n-1}$

$X_{n} = Y_{n−1} + 2Y_{n}$

$X_{n+1} = Y_{n} + 2Y_{n+1}$

$X_{n+1}$ can only take values of 0,1,2 and 3.

If it is 0 that means $Y_{n}, Y_{n+1}$ are 0,0

If it is 1 that means $Y_{n}, Y_{n+1}$ are 1,0

If it is 2 that means $Y_{n}, Y_{n+1}$ are 0,1

If it is 3 that means $Y_{n}, Y_{n+1}$ are 1,1

If I know $X_{n}$ that means I also know $Y_{n-1}, Y_{n}$ and I don't need any information from $X_{n-1}$  to calculate $X_{n+1}$. Hence, it is a Markov chain.

State-space = ${0,1,2,3}$

I need help with the initial distribution. I kind of know-how the transition matrix will look like but any help is appreciable.

Comment: Why would the state space be $\{0,1,2,3\}$? Shouldn't it be the set of non-negative integers? What if e.g. $Y_0=Y_1=Y_2=\cdots=Y_{100}=1$?

Comment: because $X_{n}$ can only take these values no matter what $Y_{n}$ is?

Comment: Oh, I misread the problem. Indeed, the state space is $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Can you help with the initial distribution and transition matrix, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $X_1$ is just the distribution of $Y_0+2Y_1$:
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=i) = \begin{cases}
(1-p)^2,& i=0\\
p(1-p),& i=1\\
p(1-p),& i=2\\
p^2,& i=3.
\end{cases}.
$$
For each positive integer $n$, conditioning on $\{X_n=0\}$ implies that $Y_{n-1}=Y_n=0$. Therefore the conditional distribution of $X_{n+1}$ is that of $2Y_{n+1}$ - zero with probability $1-p$ and two with probability $p$.

Conditioning on $\{X_n=1\}$ implies that $Y_{n-1}=1$ and $Y_n=0$, so the conditional distribution of $X_{n+1}$ is the same as when conditioning on $\{X_n=0\}$.

Conditioning on $\{X_n=2\}$ or $\{X_n=3\}$ implies that $Y_n=1$, so the conditional distribution of $X_{n+1}$ is that of $1+2Y_{n+1}$ - one with probability $1-p$ and three with probability $p$.

Therefore the transition matrix of this Markov chain is given by

$$
P = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1-p & 0 & p & 0 \\
 1-p & 0 & p & 0 \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: I had the same transition matrix, but distribution was all over the place. Maybe, I am still not able to correctly understand what initial distribution is.

Comment: @Leaderboard281923 The distribution of $X_1$ follows readily from the definition of the Bernoulli distribution and independence of $Y_0$ and $Y_1$. It may help to draw a table of the possible values of $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ with their associated probabilities, and the corresponding values of $X_1$.